# How to make grey overlay cover all site including post images and meta

Tags: css, overlay

When my menu opens I have put a greyed out overlay in the body. But it does not affect post images and some meta stuff...

Look https://imgshare.io/image/OyV9d

**CSS**

```
.is-menu-toggled-on body {
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0 2000px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 }
```

How to make the overlay cover everything...?

Comment: z-index and position might be required . your screen + bit of code is not enough to reproduce your issue, please clarify.

Comment: Doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make a overlay like this. I am showing you a regular overlay technique. use it for your code.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /*dim the background*/
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">hello</div>
```